# Tomcat stops working every time i add a new servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a web app project on eclipse.
I have a weird problem: Every time i try to add a new servlet to my project, when i try to run tomcat I get this error:

```
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

and I'm no more able to run my project.

this is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Jeans4</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>prova</display-name>
    <servlet-name>prova</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Jeans.prova</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>prova</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prova</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>FileUploadDBServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Jeans.FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUploadDBServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileUploadDBServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>BlobDisplay</display-name>
    <servlet-name>BlobDisplay</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Jeans.BlobDisplay</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BlobDisplay</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BlobDisplay</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

if i delete all my servlet tags this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.coma/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Jeans4</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

tomcat works  and doens't give me that error.

Comment: Is that the exact xml you're adding to web.xml?  If so, you need to add an opening <servlet> tag.  Also, remove the description element and use xml comments if you need to add notes about the servlet.

Answer (score 3):

Either an instance of tomcat is already running (and the 2nd instance can not run due to ports already in use), or there is some error in your configuration preventing tomcat from starting.  You need to look at the tomcat logs to determine the reason. See `"<tomcat_dir>/logs/`"

Comment: I tried to restart my computer, but i have the same problem. That's why i can't understand why there r 2 instance of tomcat
Anyway it happens every time i add a new servlet.

I tried to look at logs; inside that dir i have a lot of logs, but no one is up-to-date. the newest log file was written on october 18. there's nothing written today

Comment: How are you starting the tomcat server? From command prompt or eclipse?

Comment: From eclipse, when i run my project. I always do it this way. But from time to time it stopped working and i spend hours and hours try to find a solution. furthermore, the solution that works one time, is not going to work another time. it seems that every times there a different reason for that kind of problem

Comment: You need to figure out where your tomcat installation is running and find the log output. Tomcat will always write some output to the log on startup. It is possible Tomcat logging has been disabled/redirected, but that is not common when running Tomcat standalone or from within Eclipse.

Perhaps you have multiple Tomcat installations? Or perhaps you installed Tomcat as a service, and so it is already running when you restart your computer, thus preventing your development instance from starting?

Comment: Can you run tomcat outside of eclipse? That might work more reliably for you and help you troubleshoot the problem.

In any case, you will need to simplify, and then provide more info, in order to get any useful help.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same issue and it turned out that I forgot to include `/` in the url pattern for my servlet. So if you are using annotations for some of your servlets and, for example, you have one of your servlets annotated like this `@WebServlet("MyServletSessionContext")` instead of `@WebServlet("/MyServletSessionContext")` and try to deploy it and restart tomcat you will get this error. Make sure that you have `/` for all your urlPatterns

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Eclipse or Spring Tool Suite and used annotation **@WebServlet** in Servlet definition(java class), then you have to do put the project name as the context path when calling Servlet.
for example: my servlet is
@WebServlet(name="Employee",value="/Employee")
public class Employee extends HttpServlet {...}

and my project(module) name is JSP_Project then you should write this value in action property in form's tag or url property in ajax:

.
or
url:'/JSP_Project/Employee'
that's it.